# can you help translate dhammpada 183?

Tags: pali, translation

Would love to get a word by word trnslation to this verse dhammpada 183

Verse 183: Not to do evil, to cultivate merit, to purify one's mind - this is the Teaching of the Buddhas.

i mean what every word means   -   and yes im a bit lazy to do it not that important  but i guess some people here know pali and it will be easy for them to do  -  if it takes more than a few minutes than leave it ... its still beneficial people see this verse which i think is great

i just seen that  sabba in the first word Sabbapapassa  means "all"

and "ku salassa"    is  kusala   meaning good ?  is it made of two words ?

Sabbapapassa akaranam 
ku salassa upasampada
sacittapariyodapanam
etam buddhana sasanam.

taken from this link  :

http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=183

Comment: Click [here](https://suttacentral.net/pi/dhp#183) and hover over the words with the mouse.

Comment: It dosnt show a translation or anything when i hover over the words  (nice link non the less so thanks)

Comment: To make Thiago's suggestion work I think you need to enable the online dictionary:1) scroll to the top of the page 2) click on the "triple bar"options button on the left end of the menu bar at the top of the page 3) click on "Controls" 4) select "Pali -> English" as a lookup language. It should say "downloading dictionary" and "The lookup dictionary is now enabled. Hover with the mouse to display the meaning."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sabba - all

pāpassa - of the evil/sin/

akaraṇam-non-doing

kusalassa-of the wholesome

upasampadā-acquiring/undertaking

sacitta-own mind

pariyodapanam-purification

etam-this

buddhāna-of the Buddhas

sāsanam-teaching/dispensation

Note that “assa” means ‘of the’ (genitive singular)

Comment: and "pāp" means sin or evil ?

Comment: [Pāpa](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.2:1:2650.pali) -- "evil, wrong doing, sin"

Comment: @breath To use [the PTS dictionary](http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/pali/): 1) Type in the first few letters of the word you're searching for, enable "Search entry words only (not definitions)", and select "Words starting with  (Example: bud)" 2) If you don't find a result try again with fewer of the initial letters 3) Beware that vowels like `a` and `ā` are different 4) If you don't get a result and if the word begins with `a`, try searching for the word without the initial `a`.

Comment: Why is there a sabba=all   before  papassa    and not before kusalassa ?  
maybe the first sabba  means also the wholesome actions as well and not just the word it is attached to (papassa) ?

Comment: Yes, you can take as applying to both. There can always be a little ambiguity in sentences (in any language).  Wisdom of the reader/translator is also involved in finding a reasonable. For example: if the sentence were “the removal of all evil, the cultivation of the wholesome...”, one could ask “What’s ro be cultivated? all wholesome or only a few...”. For example, in the translation that you provided near the top of the question, “all” is left out entirely. The meaning doesn’t really change much.

Comment: just wondered if there  might be some deep meaning to the reason there was all to one of them  - or it just applies to both   ....    thanks for the reply

Comment: @breath It's verse (poetry) -- maybe that's a reason for the [number of syllables](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Buddhist-Texts/K2-Dhammapada-New/The-Prosody-of-the-Dhammapada.htm).

Comment: What about this idea :  that one should avoid all types of bad actions but dosnt have to do all types of good actions   ?  seems like a good explanation why there is an all just before the unwholesome and not before the wholesome  ....  is that also what you wrote gotamist when you wrote :

Comment: " one could ask “What’s ro be cultivated? all wholesome or only a few...”"

Answer (score 1):

I am very nice to see your question. There are at least 2 elements too deeply understand whole tipitaka, 1. tipitaka in original pāli and 2. strong memorizing that whole tipitaka-pāli.

Your doubt can not clear by word by word translation, but it will clear by deep understand each pāli-word's description.

So, I will give you word by word translation, and a link for each pāli word's description. It looks like commentary and abhidhamma, **but the fact is pāli-words link each other by themselves. I just show that pāli-relationship to you**:

> sabba-pāpassa akaraṇaṃ, kusalassa upasampadā;

Whole-unwholesome-mind ([whole 3 akusala-mind-types](https://ballwarapol.github.io/sangaha/chapter_1.htm?#6-131) and [whole 5 akusala-mind-factor-types=14 akusala-mind-factors](https://ballwarapol.github.io/sangaha/chapter_2.htm?#9-305) with [13 general mind-factors](https://ballwarapol.github.io/sangaha/chapter_2.htm?#9-139)) is not doing (by practitioner),

Whole-wholesome-mind ([whole 4 kusala-mind-types](https://ballwarapol.github.io/sangaha/chapter_1.htm?#6-420), and [whole 4 kusala-mind-factor-types=25 kusala-mind-factors](https://ballwarapol.github.io/sangaha/chapter_2.htm?#9-408) with [13 general mind-factors](https://ballwarapol.github.io/sangaha/chapter_2.htm?#9-139)) is done (by practitioner);

> sacittapariyodapanaṃ, etaṃ buddhāna sāsanaṃ.

Own-mind is perfect done to be pure (by perfect practiced arahanta-ariya; arahatta-phala [best magga-kamma's vipāka]),

This every sequence, 3 sequences, is teaching of every buddha.

> khantī paramaṃ tapo titikkhā, nibbānaṃ paramaṃ vadanti buddhā;

Khanti, Enduring, is the best of mind-practice (when you break up endure-meditation, the other meditations will finish, too).

'Nibbāna is the best (of all above line)' every buddha said the same.

> na hi pabbajito parūpaghātī, na samaṇo hoti paraṃ viheṭhayantoฯ

Especially (for to be a monk), no any the breaking-up person (=monk who is enduring to breaking above whole-unwholesome-mind) hurts the others,

No any the peace person (=monk who is enduring to meditate peaceful path such as above whole-wholesome-mind, arahatta-phala, and nibbāna) attachs the others.

> anūpavādo anūpaghāto, pātimokkhe ca saṃvaro;

(Endure to) Don't damn or hurt  anyone (by mettā meditation and karuṇa meditation),

(Endure to) observe in (5 types) saṃvara (=4 pārisuddhisīla);

> mattaññutā ca bhattasmiṃ, pantañca sayanāsanaṃ;

(Endure to) be a person who (know how to) eat smart in foods,

(Endure to) be a person who (know how to) suffice for furniture;

> adhicitte ca āyogo, etaṃ buddhāna sāsanaṃฯ

(Endure to) make an effort to meditate adhicitta (concentration meditation),

This every practice (above) is teaching of every buddha.